# Is using multiple databases and South together possible?

Tags: django, django-south, django-orm

My current project is getting extended with geographical stuff, so I'm trying to integrate GeoDjango and import some shapefiles for starters. My setup consists of the following:

1. MySQL 5.0 as 'default' database, previously the only database.
2. Spatialite as 'gis' database, should only be used to import areas from shapefiles
3. `South` is being used throughout the project

Now I've created a GeoDjango model in a new app for my areas. As usual, I've done `./manage.py schemamigration --initial` and when I tried doing `./manage.py migrate $my_new_app --database="gis"`, it failed with `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: south_migrationhistory`, which is I guess correct, since `south_migrationhistory` is in my main database.

Does anyone have any experience with such setups and can help me out?

**EDIT:** I've changed the title, since I realized this question is not actually GeoDjango-specific.

Answer (score 9):

My improved soultion:

To create the table `south_migrationhistory` in the other database:

```
./manage.py syncdb --database="my_db_name_for_apps"
```

You can now use a standard :

```
./manage.py migrate my_app
```

Here is my actual `db_router.py`

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
apps =['app1', 'app2' ]    
db_name = 'my_db_name_for_apps'

class sh_router(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models from applications in apps"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """Point all operations on apps models to db_name"""
        if model._meta.app_label in apps :
            return db_name
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """Point all operations on apps models to db_name"""
        if model._meta.app_label in apps:
            return db_name
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """Allow any relation if a model in apps is involved"""
        if obj1._meta.app_label in apps or obj2._meta.app_label in apps:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """Make sure the apps only appears on the db_name db"""
        if model._meta.app_label in ['south']:
            return True
        if db == db_name:
            return model._meta.app_label in apps
        elif model._meta.app_label in apps:
            return False
        return None
```

Comment: You probably don't want to allow cross-database relationships in your "allow_relation" method. You probably want `if obj1._state.db == obj2._state.db` rather than `if obj1._meta.app_label`...

Comment: And the first `syncdb` command will create ALL your apps' tables in the destination db, plus the django auth tables -- not just the `south_migrationhistory` table that you need.

Comment: _allow_migrate_ allows to determine which models should go to the given database.

Answer (score 9):

I found all the answers to be somewhat inaccurate, therefore, here is a summary.

First of all, everybody should of course read the very few lines about multiple databases in [the South documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/databaseapi.html) :)

The way to do this is to manually edit migration files to point to the correct database. The easiest way is to add this to the top of all files:

```
from south.db import dbs
db = dbs['name_of_you_nondefault_db']
```

The basic reason is that South does not pick up the name of the database from your database routers. This feature is simply not implemented and probably never will be with the coming of Django 1.7.

But to get things started, run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Now, you have the south_migrationhistory table. Then to migrate your special database, do:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

The south_migrationhistory will *NOT* be created in every database, only the default one. So migration history can be kept centralized.

### Multiple databases with different copies of the same application

In case you have multiple databases that you need to migrate the same application inside, you should not use a singular migration history.

Instead, create the south_migrationhistory like so:

```
python manage.py sql south | PGOPTIONS="-c search_path=NAME_OF_YOUR_SCHEMA_TO_CREATE_IN" python manage.py dbshell --database=name_of_you_nondefault_db
```

Now, you should run your migration specifying **BOTH** the app_label and the database to get the south_migrationhistory from.

```
python manage.py migrate name_of_app --database=name_of_you_nondefault_db
```

Comment: I tried your example of overriding the database but it still doesn't seem to apply my migration. The initial migration works, but not subsequent ones.

Answer (score 5):

In my `db_router.py` file I just uncomment the `'south'` app in my apps list.
I launch a `syncdb`  to create the table `south_migrationhistory` in the `otherdb` database.

```
./manage.py syncdb --database="otherdb"
```

And next comment again  the `'south'` app in my apps list.

You can now use a standard

```
./manage.py migrate my_app --database="otherdb"
```

Here is my `db_router.py`

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

apps =['app1',
     'app2',
     'south', # <<<---------------- Comment / Uncomment here
   ]

db_name = 'otherdb'

class sh_router(object):
"""A router to control all database operations on models from applications in apps"""

  def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """Point all operations on apps models to db_name"""
    if model._meta.app_label in apps :
        return db_name
    return None

  def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """Point all operations on apps models to db_name"""
    if model._meta.app_label in apps:
        return db_name
    return None

  def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """Allow any relation if a model in apps is involved"""
    if obj1._meta.app_label in apps or obj2._meta.app_label in apps:
        return True
    return None

  def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
    """Make sure the apps only appears on the db_name db"""
    if db == db_name:
        return model._meta.app_label in apps
    elif model._meta.app_label in apps:
        return False
    return None
```

Comment: This is nearly the identical solution I came up with. The only thing I was missing was commenting/uncommenting the south. Thanks.

Comment: Note, this is still an incomplete solution, since you can't run ./manage.py migrate to migrate both databases. The migrates for one database will be picked up by South when migrating the other database.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomasz said, you have to syncdb your "gis" db too in order to create all the required tables, including south_migrationhistory.

```
./manage.py syncdb --database=gis
```

Comment: You need to specify a router, or otherwise you'll add all your apps to the other database, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Django 1.7 has allow_migrate() in its database router class to address this.

For earlier Djangos:

- you need south_migrationhistory in any db where you want migrations
- do a regular `syncdb` to put all the regular auth_* etc. tables in the `default` db
- that will put south_migrationhistory in `default`
- don't do `syncdb --database=other`, that will duplicate all the auth_* etc.
  tables in `other`
- instead, copy the `south_migrationhistory` table from `default` to `other`, e.g.

  `sqlite3 main.sqlite ".sc south_migrationhistory" | sqlite3 other.sqlite`

  or equivalent pg_dump command or whatever
- then use `migrate --database=other`

At least this gets everything in the right place until you migrate to 1.7 :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is old but I had the same problem and Google got me that thread.

So first you need to change the way you do your datamigration:

```
    def forwards(self, orm):
    "Write your forwards methods here."                               
        obj = orm.Obj()
        obj.name = 'my name'
        obj.save(using=db.db_alias)
```

The variable db.db_alias contain the name of the db to be used, so you will need to do everything with 'usgin' and use db.db_alias as the db name.

then you run your migration with
./mange migrate App --database=DB_NAME

in case of schemamigration just directly use db.function like south does.

Answer (score -2):

You probably want to have south_migrationhistory in both databases, so syncdb to "gist" for south app. Then your migration should go just fine.

Comment: Any ideas how to get South to put it in both databases?